# Comparing a string with an array list to see if the string contains anything from the list

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, contains

I have an area where a When the string is submitted, I want to check if that string contains anything from an arrayList. For example, in the arrayList I might have the strings `"visit"` and `"enter"`. The user could enter something like `"enter village"` or `"visit cave"`. I just want to be able to compare the string to the arrayList to detect for any keywords. If it has keyword from the list, it can act accordingly. The code I have right now looks like this:

`if(enterList.contains(text)) //code goes here;`

with `text` being the string the user enters. But the way this works is the opposite of what I want. Its seeing if `enterList` contains `text`, not if `text` contains anything from `enterList`. Is there any way to see if anything in a string contains anything in a list?

Comment: What do you mean by text contains anything from enterList?

Comment: Try a `for` loop: `for (String word : enterList) if (text.contains(word)) return true; return false;`

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari what I mean is I want to see if anything in the arrayList is in the string called text. So even if the string is "visit village" and the arrayList only contains a string equal to "visit", it'll detect that text contains something from the list.

Comment: @TechBandit Got it. Then you have to use for loop as Andreas said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try with this First split your string by space into array and compare the array with you list like

```
String[] splited = text.split("\\s+");
if(Collections.disjoint(yourArray, Arrays.asList(splited ))){
//your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code also gets you the tokens that are present and not simply if any of them are present or not.

```
List<String> listWords; // List of Words against which checking will happen
String sentence; // Concerned String to check

...

Stream.of(sentence.split("[ |.]"))
      .filter(token -> listWords.contains(token))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The above just prints the token encountered. You can alter the code as follows for adding further logic.

```
Stream.of(sentence.split("[ |.]"))
      .filter(token -> listWords.contains(token))
      .forEach(f -> {
          // Your logic here
      });
```